# .htaccess on Ngnix: only allow access to images for one .php page

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

Ngnix only allows some .htaccess rules but I have a hard time figuring out which. I have a password protected index.php to display images on the page. Those images are located in a folder that i want to secure aswell. I try to make it happen with .htaccess like this:

```
SetEnvIf Referer domain\.de internal
<Files *>
order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=internal
</Files>
```

it works partly, so that the direct url to the image does not display it, but generates a 403. but i need to specify the url more, to the specific index.php file where the images should only be displayed. otherwise, the images can be displayed on any page of my domain with the image url.
the full url of the index.php is something like:
https://subdomain.domain.de/folder/index.php
so in my opinion the htaccess should look like this:

```
SetEnvIf Referer https://subdomain\.domain\.de\/folder\/index.php internal
<Files *>
order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=internal
</Files>
```

but it does not work. the images are still accessible from other pages.

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Are they actually accessible via a new request with an empty cache? Or did you go to your special page before, your browser loaded the images and cached them - and is now serving them _from_ cache on those other pages as well, without making a new request to the server?

Comment: hey, it's possible with a new request. for example if i have the image url and i open another browser, i can load the image by putting the link into an <a href> tag. i guess, because that request will come from the correct domain. thats why i need to specify more, so only a certan page of the domain can make the request